# Regex for variable declaration and initialization in c#

Tags: c#, regex, variables, declaration

I want to write a RegEx to pull out all the variable values and their names from the variable declaration statement. Say i have

int i,k = 10,l=0

i want to write a regex something like int\s^,?|(^,?)*
but this will also accept
k = 10 i.e. (without int preceding it)
Basically idea is
If string starts with int then
get the variable list seperated by ,

i know to extract csv values, but here my string has some initial value as well. How can i resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start thinking about the structure of a definition, say,

```
(a line can start with some spaces) followed by,

(Type) followed by

(at least one space)
(variable_1)
(optionally
   (comma // next var
    |
    '='number // initialization
    ) ...`
```

then try to convert each group:

```
^      \s*    \w+           \s+        \w+         ?          (','    |  '=' \d+   ) ...
line  some    type          at least  var          optionally   more  or init some
start spaces  (some chars)  one space (some chars)              vars     val  digits
```

Left as homework to remove spaces and fix up the final regex.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some useful information which you can use

http://compsci.ca/v3/viewtopic.php?t=6712

Answer (score 0):

You could build up your regular expression from the [C# Grammar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664812(VS.71).aspx). But building a parser would certainly be better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 ^(int|[sS]tring)\s+\w+\s*(=\s*[^,]+)?(,\s*\w+\s*(=\s*[^,]+)?)*$
```

It'll match your example code

```
int i,k = 10,l=0
```

And making a few assumptions about the language you may or may not be using, it'll also match:

```
int i, j, k=10, l=0
string i=23, j, k=10, l=0
```