# what will be the Regular Expression to get all the property and variables names of a class in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

What will be the Regular Expression to get all the property and variables names of any class in c#, I want to parse the *.cs file. that is i want to select any *.cs file as input and it should get the property name of that selected class, as an output.

can any one help!!!....would appreciate for any help i tried very much but not got the actual result every time class name is coming instead of property.
thanks 
Jack

Comment: Please provide more informations. Why you need regular expressions ? Do you need those data at run time ?

Comment: How do you know the .cs file has only 1 class? Or any at all? What about nested classes?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585853/regex-for-variable-declaration-and-initialization-in-c-sharp ?

Comment: the question is not a duplicated of the linked one above as he also needs the class properties. He wants to use the regexs because he does not have the class working at runtime, I think he needs to parse the source file. Not sure if VS compile services or anything similar could provide what he needs as the intellisense parser surely has this feature...

Comment: @Polynomial: This isn't a duplicate. The question you linked is asking how to get all the definitions on a single line. This is asking how to get all of the field names in a class.

Comment: You can't do this with a single regular expression. You need a parser.

Comment: @JimMischel - Fair enough, I was posing it as a possible duplicate. I didn't notice the difference, thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way you're going to be able to get exactly what you want with a regular expression because you need semantic context, not just string parsing.

For example, a good first attempt at finding all of the field and property definitions in a C# file might go something like this

```
^\s*(?:(?:private|public|protected|internal)\s+)?(?:static\s+)?(?:readonly\s+)?(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s*[^(]
```

That will match properties (`public int Foo {...}`) and fields (`private int foo;`) but not methods (`protected void Bar()`).

The problem is that a regex engine has no concept of the context within which those tokens appear. It will match both `foo` and `bar` in this code:

```
int foo;
void Stuff()
{
  int bar;
}
```

If you happen to know that your code file follows some coding standards, you may have more luck. For example, if you enforce a style rule that all class members must have access specifiers, then you can make the private/public/etc part of that regex non-optional; since those are only permitted at the class level, it will filter out local variables.

There are other options, none of them too attractive at first glance. There is persistent talk from the C# dev team about exposing the C# compiler as a service in some future version of .NET, which would be perfect here, but I wouldn't expect that any time soon. You could purchase a third-party C# parser/analyzer like [this one](http://inevitablesoftware.com/Products.aspx) (caveat: I have zero experience with that, it's just the first Google hit). You could try compiling the .cs file using `csc` and examining the IL, but you'd need to know all of the third-party references.

Comment: I think the Mono compiler could be used for this too.